# Browser back-button displays the preserved page state sent by server but any DOM modifications done using javascript is not getting preserved

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom, browser-cache, back-button

The code snippet (**in C#**) that is used to trigger the JavaScript code from code-behind is as:

```
int returnValue = SaveStudent("John", "XII"); // SaveStudent() is a C# function that saves the student details in DB and returns studentId.
hdnStudentId = returnValue ; // hdnStudentId is a hidden-field control
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), 
                          "ShowStudent", "showStudentDetails();",true);
```

The definition of "showStudentDetails()" JavaScript method is as:

```
function showStudentDetails(){
     If($('[id*=hdnStudentId]').val() > 0){
         // show the popup
     }
}
```

Here is the description of the issue:

- In a web-page 'WebPage1.APSX', after saving the data in DB, I display
  a bootstrap popup using ScriptManager Class (as mentioned above).
- Here I set the value of a hidden-field variable to the inserted rowid
  that is inserted in DB(say 12345) .
- The ScriptManager class
  successfully registers the script in DOM and displays the popup.
- Thereafter I reset the Here hidden-field variable to -1. In the
  popup, I have a button control that redirects to another page
  'WebPage1.APSX'.

  $('[id*=hdnStudentId]').val('-1');
- Now user clicks on 'browser back-button', it doesn't hit the server-side code and
  renders the UI based on previous instance of page sent by server.
- As this is previous instance of page sent by server, hidden-field
  variable gets set to '12345' instead of -1 (not sure why, we already
  did reset the value to -1) and display the popup again.

**Requirement**: When user clicks on 'browser back-button', we need to remember the previously manipulated data in DOM as well(i.e. $('[id*=hdnStudentId]').val('-1');) so that we can avoid to display the popup on browser back-button click.

Comment: Hi Folks, kindly reply. I'll be thankful to you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to checkout Browser history API to save your page state in the history when no server involved, here is mdn doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

> The DOM `window` object provides access to the browser's history through
>   the `history` object. It exposes useful methods and properties that let
>   you move back and forth through the user's history, as well as --
>   starting with HTML5 -- manipulate the contents of the history stack

and also an example of Ajax navigation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Example. hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks..It is really a good idea, but I am facing few issues while implementing it in multiple web-pages(around 10 .aspx pages).
So, I tried to keep it in MasterPage. But faced issues in getting the previous page. **ISSUE:** On click on page-link, the previous-page is the 'existing before' page but on page-refresh also, it loads the previous page. Moreover, the URL that gets shown on browser also changes wrongly.
The code snippet of Master page is placed in next comment as the 'number of characters of this reply istoo long'.

Comment: Here is the code snippet of Master page:
The codes are commented out because those are not working as expected:
//history.pushState(null, null, document.referrer);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
   //history.pushState(null, null, document.referrer);
   //history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
     alert('Hi, You clicked browser-back button');
});

Comment: Have you considered that it might be due to passing dynamic references to the `pushState()` I wouldn't recommend passing dynamic arguments like `document.referrer` or `window.location.href` . I guess it's better to do like, `var stateObj = { id: hdnStudentId};
history.pushState(stateObj, null, "#popup");` `#` after URL is general pattern for client side only URLs which will be handled by JS.  and then in your event listener you can call the function `showStudentDetails(stateObj.id)` and that means extending your function to accept arguments too.

Comment: Your JavaScript needs to save the required data  to render the DOM back to a known state by.  saving (push state) and retrieving (popState) data to the history object. There's no magic here!

Comment: Thanks @Salus .. I followed your advise.. And finally the following code-snippet worked for me..
I used 'history.pushState();' method just after showing the popup:
$('#divStudentDetails').modal('show');
history.pushState(null, null, "");

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Salus .. I followed your advise.. And finally the following code-snippet worked for me..
I used 'history.pushState();' method just after showing the popup:

```
$('#divStudentDetails').modal('show');
history.pushState(null, null, "");
```